# Is it possible to query the LUN ID of a list of windows server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, storage, storage-area-network, lun

I'm trying a combination of FCINFO and PSEXEC to get the LUN ID (LUN NUMBER) used by servers, but i cant get this information directly from fcinfo.

I've also try using WMI until i learned that i should know the wmi namespace of the lun controller installed on each server.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you've resolved this issue yet...However this may be possible using Powershell.

You can try the same using the The Get-DiskScsiLun function available in Powershell

The Get-DiskScsiLun function uses the following WMI objects:
Win32_LogicalDisk, 
Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition, 
Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition and 
Win32_DiskDrive.

For more details please refer
http://rvdnieuwendijk.com/2012/05/29/powershell-function-to-get-disk-scsi-lun-number/

Cheers!